# ssh-пользователь не имеет "полноценного" доступа, как настроить?

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование, can

ssh-пользователь не имеет "полноценного"  доступа, как настроить ??

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается ssh-пользователю поднять и запустить CAN интерфейс.

```
$ ip link set can0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

попробовал через команду `ip addr flush dev can0` команду проглотил.

```
$ ip addr flush dev can0
$ ip link set can0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Также пытался сеть перезагрузить(ssh-клиентом), но увы линукс не дал мне такой возможности.

```
 init.d/networking restart
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'networking.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to restart networking.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
 failed!
```

Что надо сделать чтоб ssh-пользователь мог работать с CAN -интерфейсом ???

Также замечу когда я захожу под СОМ соединению под (root) под главным пользователем,то всё работает. **Как настроить ssh-пользователя чтоб он имел такие же возможности пользователь root ???**

---

Дал права через  `/etc/sudoers` добавил строку `testssh ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
testssh ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d


# User privilege specification
```

перезагрузил `service ssh restart`

Увы всё равно не заработало :( так и непонял что не так ???

Comment: Под каким пользователем вы проходите авторизацию по ssh? Если он отличен от root, то ему необходимо дать права к примеру через `/etc/sudoers` Добавив в конце файла строку по типу `имя пользователя ALL=(root)       ALL`, теперь у этого пользователя будут полные права при запуске через `sudo комманда`. Более подробная информация `man sudoers`

Comment: @PotroNik  обновил вопрос

Comment: А как вводите команду, sudo вначале указываете? При выполнении он должен запросить пароль от testssh, после ввода все должно работать.

Comment: @PotroNik оформите пожалуйста как ответ (можете по сути комментарий накидать а я дополню принтскринами ) , да заработало хоть и ругался что не понимает команд :3

Comment: Думаю, что `su` решит эти проблемы :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настройка пользователя для запуска команд от имени пользователя:

в конфигурационный файл /etc/sudoers добавить строку

```
user hosts = (runas) commands
```

- **users** - пользователь или группа пользователей ( в данном случае testssh)
- **hosts** - хосты на которые открываем доступ (ALL - все)
- **runas** - имя пользователя от чьего имени производим запуск (или ALL - от имени любого пользователя от которых можно выполнить команду)
- **commands** список команд (или ALL - все команды доступные пользователю от чьего имени производим запуск)

Так же выполненять команд от имени другого пользователя можно без ввода собственного пароля

```
%testssh ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

регулируется это параметром NOPASSWD:

Пример запуск команд:

```
sudo ls -l; sudo df -h; sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

---

Если на сервере отсутствует команда `sudo`, то ее необходимо установить:

- centos: yum install sudo
- debian:
  apt-get install sudo

---

Крайне не рекомендуется давай все права всем пользователям, выдавать права нужно по потребности, к примеру есть пользователь vasiliy и он хочет управлять zabbix-proxy, можно выдать ему соответствующие права только на это:

```
vasiliy ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/zabbix-proxy
```

---

P.S. вы писали в комментариях:

> да заработало хоть и ругался что не понимает команд

вероятнее всего это различие переменных окружений PATH, сравните выводы `echo $PATH` по пользователем root и testssh

---

В комментариях еще было подмечено, что sudo не единственный выход из положения, возможно после соединения по ssh выполнять `su - root` если вам известен пароль от суперпользователя.

Comment: `вероятнее всего это различие переменных окружений PATH`. У рута есть доступ к `/sbin` а также `/usr/local/sbin` и `/usr/sbin` через PATH. `sbin` содержит утилиты только для [суперпользователя](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local/308048#308048). По этой причине команды типа `sysctl`, `mount.cifs`, `swapon` и другие при запуске без sudo и без указания пути не будут найдены (`command not found: mount.cifs`).